# Show value in Preferences in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, preferences, settings.bundle

I have a `Settings.bundle` and inside there i have one `Root.plist`.

In that i have a `PSSliderPrefernce` and i want to show its value when a user set a value in device `Settings` page.

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: please be more specific. what do you want to do

Comment: please check the edit. i want the value of slider to be shown above the slider..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a UILabel in your UI, write a method like:

```
//method for your slider
-(void)sliderValueChanged
{
   [yourLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", yourSlider.value]];
}
```